# Как настроить отступ в четыре пробела в SASS при компиляции в CSS?

Tags: sass

Koala App при компиляции SASS в CSS делает отступ в 2 пробела по умолчанию.

Подскажите, как настроить отступ в 4 пробела? В каком файле конфиг?

Comment: Но зачем???​​​​

Comment: Следуя стайлгаду проекта - четыре пробела.

Comment: С каких пор стайлгайд распространяется на _сгенерированные файлы?_ Там вообще логичнее без пробелов настроить с минификацией и map-файлом для отладки.

Comment: А почему вы отвечаете вопросом на вопрос?

Comment: На выходе необходим не сжатый CSS файл соответствующий сталгайду написания кода, в котором четко прописано 4 пробела.

Comment: Потому что это комментарии, а не ответы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вообще пользоваться коалой для компиляции?) Почитайте про таск-раннеры, а именно про Gulp. Там можно тоже скомпилировать ваш sass-файл и пропустить его через csscomb, который отредактирует ваш код по стайлгайду. Вот сайт, на котором можно сгенерировать файл с настройками стайлгайда для csscomb - http://csscomb.com/ , вот статья на хабре про csscomb - https://habrahabr.ru/post/230589/ . Вот статья про таск-раннер Gulp, в которой достаточно хорошо объясняют как писать таски и в процессе собирается достаточно хороший галпфайл для старта, так-же там прилагается видео - http://webdesign-master.ru/blog/tools/2016-03-09-gulp-beginners.html. Gulp значительно упростит жизнь, чем бредовая коала, так что стоит потратить пару часиков, чтобы разобраться и написать свой первый галпфайл =)

P.S. Почитал комментарии и тоже не понял зачем стайлгайд для CSS. Если уж пользуетесь SASS`ом, то команда должна писать вся на нем, наверное, и должен быть стайлгайд непосредственно для него.

Comment: Вопросу 1.5 года))

Comment: И правда, не посмотрел...)))

Comment: Ладно, может кому-нибудь пригодится)